# Calling matlab from java, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, matlab, javafx

I am trying to call a matlab function I have from java (developing in Eclipse). I can get it to run just fine with R2019b, but when I change the java build path to R2019a (engine.jar - C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\extern\engines\java\jar), I get an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mathworks.mvm.MvmFactory.nativeSetJavaEngine(Z)V
    at com.mathworks.mvm.MvmFactory.nativeSetJavaEngine(Native Method)
    at com.mathworks.mvm.MvmImpl.setJavaEngineMode(MvmImpl.java:203)
    at com.mathworks.engine.MatlabEngine.<clinit>(MatlabEngine.java:69)
    at MyController.onRunSimClick(MyController.java:190)
    ... 62 more
```

I have added both C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\bin\win64 and C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\bin\win64 to my PATH variable.

The start of the stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Method com.mathworks.mvm.MvmFactory.nativeCreateFactory(IIZ[Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)J not found
```

I am happy to provide the rest, but don't want to create clutter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you set the `PATH` variable ? I mean via **Environment Variable** from start menu or via command prompt console. If console, I suggest set it via accessing environment variables from start menu and then retry.

Comment: I've set the PATH from both Eclipse in the Run/Debug settings, appending the variable to the native environment, and from the system level on my machine. I've not done so from the console, but I suspect I would have no more luck, but worth a try.

Comment: I'm using jre 1.8.0_251 in eclipse. In Matlab R2019a, my java version is 1.8.0_181 and in Matlab R2019b, my java version is 1.8.0_202. I don't believe these should have any impact though.

Comment: Please make sure that your system, MATLAB and Eclipse are using the same Java version as MATLAB.

Comment: Okay, I've got all of them using 1.8.0_251, still the same error occurs.

Comment: Have you edited the Windows Environment PATH variable to include C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin\win64\ . Then, Make all the dlls needed for java by including this command line argument in the run configuration: -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin\win64".

Comment: I have done that - no help there unfortunately. Why would adding R2016b work though? I am trying to use R2019a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, where I can just compile and run my code from the command line. I had to add C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\bin\win64; to my path before any other matlab version. Then, as per the matlab documentation I could just do:

```
> javac -classpath matlabroot\extern\engines\java\jar\engine.jar MyJavaCode.java
> java -classpath .;matlabroot\extern\engines\java\jar\engine.jar MyJavaCode
```

I'm still not sure why this wouldn't work in Eclipse, but this workaround will work for the short term.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so putting this in as an answer. The first thing you might want to do is run:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

to see what your java.library.path is.